# GPL vs. obligatory warranty

Tags: gpl, warranty

There are many countries on the world, where distributing products means to accept an obligatory warranty well.

More clearly: if you buy a mainboard, and it is bad, the seller *must* re-take it (with payback) on certain (broadly formulated) circumstances. For example, they can't sell cheaper mainboard without warranty, it is forbidden by law.

But GPL (as I know, both of 2 and 3) closes out any warranty.

Does it mean, that GPL software can't be distributed in these countries?

Comment: An alternative to the warranty in these countries is to refund the full purchase price. If you give someone a free mainboard, and something goes wrong, then there's no warranty required - you can just give a $0 refund.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert It is country - dependent, I think if you buy his old mainboard from your friend for cash, it is probably exempt practically everywhere.

Comment: Sure, you need to check local legislation, but I'm sure (without actually checking) that a full refund is always an option in every country where warranties are required. I you buy a pen for $2, and it's faulty, they're not going to ship your pen off to be repaired and they are not required to have replacement pens available. You just get a refund and buy a different pen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The GPL permits warranties:

> 11. BECAUSE THE PROGRAM IS LICENSED FREE OF CHARGE, THERE IS NO WARRANTY FOR THE PROGRAM, TO THE EXTENT PERMITTED BY APPLICABLE LAW.
>       EXCEPT WHEN OTHERWISE STATED IN WRITING THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND/OR
>       OTHER PARTIES

So:

1. if the law requires a warranty, there's a warranty.
2. if someone states otherwise for whatever reason, there's a warranty.

Also note:

> You may charge a fee for the physical act of transferring a copy, and
>   you may at your option offer warranty protection in exchange for a
>   fee.

And even:

> c) If the modified program normally reads commands interactively when
>   run, you must cause it, when started running for such interactive use
>   in the most ordinary way, to print or display an announcement
>   including an appropriate copyright notice and a notice that there is
>   no warranty (or else, saying that you provide a warranty) and that
>   users may redistribute the program under these conditions, and telling
>   the user how to view a copy of this License. (Exception: if the
>   Program itself is interactive but does not normally print such an
>   announcement, your work based on the Program is not required to print
>   an announcement.)